# Is it OK to multiply a decimal with an int?

Tags: c#, .net, int, decimal, type-conversion

I'm a newbie to C# and .NET, so I apoligize if this is a too simple question.

I have a decimal variable `decVar`.
I need to multiply it with an integer variable `intVar`.
I need the result to be `decimal`.
So should I then declare the integer variable as `int` or as `decimal`?

Having this code,

```
decimal decVar = 0.1m;
decimal decRes = decVar * intVar;
```

should I declare it like this:

```
int intVar = 3;
```

or like this:

```
decimal intVar = 3;
```

?

This is a financial calculation, so I need the result to be exactly `0.3`.

**upd** : Code updated (thanks to Jon)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It doesn't matter - the `int` will be converted to `decimal` anyway: there isn't a `*(decimal, int)` operator, just `*(int, int)` and `*(decimal, decimal)`. (And other types, of course.)

Now `decimal` can't be implicitly converted to `int`, but the reverse conversion is valid - so that's what the compiler does.

However, you'll need to change the declaration of `decVar` as currently the right hand side of the assignment operator is a double, not a decimal. You mean 0.1m. You'll want semi-colons too :)

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't make a difference. Since one argument of the multiplication is `decimal`, the other one will be converted to `decimal` as well (if it is not already one).

This conversion is [always safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k2e8atx.aspx):

> **Conversion Considerations**
>
> This type provides methods that convert Decimal values to and from
>   SByte, Int16, Int32, Int64, Byte, UInt16, UInt32, and UInt64.
>   Conversions from these integral types to Decimal are widening
>   conversions that never lose information or throw exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether you declare it as `int` or `decimal`. It will get cast to `decimal` for the calculation.

Also you can never guarantee floating point accuracy because there are numbers that can't be  represented exactly in binary. You will have to take other precautions to minimise rounding errors.

Comment: Upvoting for pointing out problems with binary representation of floats.

Comment: There are numbers that can't be represented exactly in decimal, too.  For example 1m / 5m is not imprecise, but 1d / 5d is.